# Playing sound in Docker container on WSL in Windows 11

Tags: windows, docker, audio, wsl-2

Newer versions of Windows ([build 21364 or later](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/the-initial-preview-of-gui-app-support-is-now-available-for-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2/)) enable GUI support in WSL2, including full audio support. This is pretty amazing.

Given that WSL2 now supports audio, how do we then get audio to work inside a Docker container running on Windows, using Docker's WSL2 engine?

On a Linux host, you can simply invoke a Docker image with e.g `--device /dev/snd`.

What is the equivalent command to run a sound-enabled Docker image from the Windows command line?

Comment: Not that I've tried, but if your info is correct you should be able to do `--device /dev/snd` from inside WSL.

Comment: Unfortunately /dev/snd does not exist in the updated WSL. I believe ALSA is sending audio directly to Pulseaudio which is then being forwarded to Windows.

Answer (score 7):

There is no `/dev/snd` or direct audio hardware emulation available in WSL, even in the new Windows 11 setup. Instead, the newest release of WSL achieves audio output by pointing PulseAudio clients to an external PulseAudio server via a socket in `/mnt/wslg/`. This server runs on *yet another* Linux distro calleed WSLg that runs inside Windows for the sole purpose of plumbing audio and graphical data between *your* WSL distro and Windows.

It looks a bit like this:

```
Docker container <-> WSL <-> WSLg <-> Windows 11
```

The actual PulseAudio server is located in WSLg. The location of the socket is stored in the environment variable `PULSE_SERVER`:

```
# On WSL   
echo $PULSE_SERVER
/mnt/wslg/PulseServer
```

So, aside from making sure your Dockerfile has a basic PulseAudio installation (`RUN apt-get install -y pulseaudio` or equivalent), all you need to do is invoke the image like:

In WSL:

```
docker run -t -i -e "PULSE_SERVER=${PULSE_SERVER}" -v /mnt/wslg/:/mnt/wslg/ image_name
```

Or from the Windows command line like:

```
wsl docker run -t -i -e "PULSE_SERVER=/mnt/wslg/PulseServer" -v /mnt/wslg/:/mnt/wslg/ image_name
```

Or

```
docker run -t -i -e "PULSE_SERVER=/mnt/wslg/PulseServer" -v \\wsl$\Ubuntu\mnt\wslg:/mnt/wslg/ image_name
```

Comment: I'm sure I had this working the other day, but now I'm getting:

>docker run --rm -e "PULSE_SERVER=/mnt/wslg/PulseServer" -v /mnt/wslg/:/mnt/wslg/ nalbion/whisper-cpp-base                            
init: found 0 capture devices:
init: attempt to open default capture device ...
ALSA lib confmisc.c:855:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5178:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_inum returned error: No such file or directory

Comment: Ah - you need to add to your Dockerfile `RUN apt-get install -y libsdl2-dev`

Comment: This was able to get this sample working
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("hello")
engine.runAndWait()
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true
xcb_connection_has_error() returned true

However I still get issues with ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
etc ...
Full error log found here: https://github.com/KoljaB/RealtimeTTS/issues/59